# JPA query extremely slow when setMaxResults is set

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

In a particular project, I am facing a problem with a typed query in different configuration.

When setting on a TypedQuery a maxResults value greater than the actual number of results returned by a query, getResultList() takes a really long time to execute (sometimes up to 350 seconds to retrieve 10 rows composed of 6 columns).

In contrast, the same query without setMaxResults takes around 15 seconds to execute. The same query with `WHERE` parameters changed to retrieve a larger number of results is also really fast.

I'm testing all of this in a Junit test class with a resource-local datasource, but the same happens with a JTA datasource on Weblogic 10.3.6 (as well as Jboss EAP 6.1 but I don't think it is relevant).

I tried to play with `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` and `hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets` in persistence.xml, but it's pretty hard to estimate if there is an improvement: once the query succeeded and thus has been cached by Oracle, it will be fast to execute no matter how I adapt those values (I don't have the privileges to clear Oracle's statement cache).

I noticed that if I remove the `ORDER BY` from the query, the execution time drops to 50-60 seconds, which is still way too long but still less than 350 seconds. The column is indexed, though (it is a primary key), thus I don't understand why it impacts the performance that much.

I'm building my query with the Criteria API, but I also tried with HQL or native SQL. I'm using [CriteriaQuery#multiSelect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect%28java.util.List%29) to retrieve only the needed fields, and then assign the results to a class with an appropriate constructor (`select new ...`).

Here is the query as translated by Hibernate:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT message0_.MESG_ID  AS col_0_0_,
    message0_.CREATION_DATE  AS col_1_0_,
    messagetyp1_.MSGT_ID     AS col_2_0_,
    message0_.MESSAGE_NAME   AS col_3_0_,
    interview2_.INVW_ID      AS col_4_0_,
    interview2_.IVWT_ID      AS col_5_0_,
    party3_.LICENSE_USERNAME AS col_6_0_
  FROM  message0_
  LEFT OUTER JOIN S399_MESSAGE_TYPES messagetyp1_
  ON message0_.MSGT_ID=messagetyp1_.MSGT_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN S399_INTERVIEWS interview2_
  ON message0_.INVW_ID=interview2_.INVW_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN S399_PARTIES party3_
  ON message0_.PRTY_ID          =party3_.PRTY_ID
  WHERE message0_.CREATION_DATE>=?
  AND (interview2_.IS_POLLING  IS NULL
  OR interview2_.IS_POLLING     =0)
  ORDER BY message0_.MESG_ID DESC
  )
WHERE rownum <= ?
```

When I run this in SQLDeveloper, it is fast (as it should be), less than a second generally.

When I debug Hibernate's code, I can see that it is `org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(PreparedStatement)` that is abnormally slow, on `ps.executeQuery()`. Should it point me towards a JDBC driver problem or rather towards a database problem?

Thanks in advance for any advice or idea about this situation.

Configuration:

- Java 6
- Hibernate 3.6.10 (JPA 2.0) (tried to upgrade to Hibernate 4 and JPA 2.1, no change)
- Oracle database 11g (11.1.0.7.0)
- Oracle jdbc driver 11.2.0.3 (tried with 11.1.0.7.0 and 11.2.0.4, no change).
- hibernate.dialect: Oracle10gDialect.

Possible duplicate: [ResultSet.next very slow only when query contains FIRST_ROWS or ROWNUM restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861332/resultset-next-very-slow-only-when-query-contains-first-rows-or-rownum-restricti)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the `/*+ FIRST_ROWS */` hint. If it doesn't help you'll have to find out what Hibernate is actually executing.

**Update:** How much data (in term of MB) does your query have to look at? Is 15 seconds response time reasonable at all? Could you provide an "explain plan" of that query?

Looking at the query, it seems that you should have an index on `message0_.CREATION_DATE`. You could try to provide an upper bound in the where clause. Like Tom Kytes always says ... Think about it! If you query data between a certain date in the past and now, and you do not pass in the upper bound (SYSTIMESTAMP) - you're basicly expecting the database to go long ways to know that it's still worthwile to use that index on the date column. Oracle does stuff like "bind parameter peeking" - it'll even look at the the actual **values** of the bounds you provide and it may decide for a different query plan if it thinks that'll cost less....

Do you realize that ORDER BY is evaluated **after** the where clause? That means, you won't get the first n records according to your order by, but n random records which are then ordered....

Comment: I would like to try to avoid to use hints as they are not supported by Hibernate. Furthermore, I think you are wrong when you say that `ORDER BY` is evaluated after the where clause in this case, as my query uses a subquery (`select * from (...) where rownum <= ?`). See this often referenced article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: it's important that the `order by` is placed in the inner query. I was wondering because your original question doesn't show it.